# How do I insert items into a dictionary in Object Pascal?

Tags: dictionary, delphi, pascal

I would like to insert many elements into a dictionary in Object Pascal without using the .add() method many times, as in this example:

```
//SOURCE FROM C++
    const map<string, Element> _Table = {
        
        { "H" , Element("Hydrogen",     1, 1.00784f)},
        { "He", Element("Helium",       2, 4.0026f)},
        { "Li", Element("Lithium",      3, 6.941f)}
    };
```

In Object Pascal I should do this to add these 3 elements with the "traditional" method:

```
  TElement := Element.Create;
  TElement.FullName := 'Hyrogen';
  TElement.AtomicNumber := 1;
  TElement.Weight := 1.00784;
  Table.Add('H', TElement);

  { and so on }
```

I wonder if it is possible to do this assignment of values ​​in Obj Pascal as in C ++

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: `TElement := Element.Create;` looks extremely wrong. Surely you mean `Element := TElement.Create;` and no other `T`s.

Comment: In any case, it is impossible for us to answer you Q without knowing the types of `Element` and `Table`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a constructor for `Element` to simplify its creation, eg:

```pascal
Table.Add('H', Element.Create('Hyrogen', 1, 1.00784));
```

To add items to a `TDictionary` during its creation, you will need to create a `TEnumerable<T>` object that enumerates a collection of `TPair<string, Element>` items, and then you can pass that object to the `TDictionary` constructor. For instance, `TList<T>` derives from `TEnumerable<T>`, eg:

```
type
  ElementPair = TPair<string, Element>;

List := TList<ElementPair>.Create;
List.Add(ElementPair.Create('H', Element.Create(...)));
...
Table := TDictionary<string, Element>.Create(List);
...
```

But, making a `TList` of `TPair`s is not much better than just calling `TDictionary.Add()` directly, unless you were to create a list 1 time and then reuse it to create multiple dictionaries.